# Is there a method in R to update specific cells of a dataframe with user input?

Tags: r, dataframe, prompt, readline

Disclaimer: Save the odd script or two, I'm still fairly new to R/coding, AND this is my first post here ever, so please be gentle. I apologize for how vague things may be, I simply don't have the coding vocabulary at this point in time to best describe what I'm trying to do.

Anyway:

I have a dataframe where column `b` describes the amount of cookies, `x`, left in a jar and column `a` contains the names of all the jars, `y`, from which the cookies were taken.

This dataframe needs routine updating due to the high volume and frequency of cookies taken from many different jars.

As of now, I have a script that will pull from a master list of jars and cookies and write a csv containing only jars required for the order and how many cookies are left in each jar.

I would like to add some `readline(prompt)` that will ask the user something like  "Amount of cookies taken from Jar `z`: " for each Jar in the order and then update that exact cell in the master list of jars and cookies with the provided user input.

I know how to do everything I've mentioned here EXCEPT how to tell R to include `z` in the user prompt.

So, in other terms, if I have an order form where someone requested cookies from jars 5, 11, and 31 how do I tell R to prompt:

'Amount of cookies taken from JAR 5: ' 
wait for input 
'Amount of cookies taken from JAR 11: ' 
wait for input 
'Amount of cookies taken from JAR 31: ' 
wait for input

Comment: You can `paste()` values together to make a string `name <- "Joe"; paste("Hello", name)`

Comment: Adding on to @MrFlick... `prompt_1 <- paste("Amount of cookies taken from JAR", z); cookies_taken_1 <- readline(prompt_1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it using a `for` loop.

1) we can define a dummy dataframe:

```r
df <- data.frame(Jars = LETTERS[1:5],
                 Cookie = sample(1:50,5))
```

So your dataframe looks like:

```r
> df
  Jars Cookie
1    A      9
2    B     17
3    C     23
4    D     34
5    E     19
```

2) Then, the code for iterating through the `Jars` and ask for the input for each and substract it from `Cookie` column (you can even print the current amount of cookies in each jar in order to avoid having negative results ;)):

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  x <- as.numeric(readline(paste0("How many in Jar ",df$Jars[i]," (current number:",df$Cookie[i],") : ")))
  df[i,"Cookie"] <- df[i,"Cookie"] - x
}
```

3) Now in action:

```r
> for(i in 1:nrow(df))
+   {
+     x <- as.numeric(readline(paste0("How many in Jar ",df$Jars[i]," (current number:",df$Cookie[i],") : ")))
+     df[i,"Cookie"] <- df[i,"Cookie"] - x
+   }
How many in Jar A (current number:9) :  0
How many in Jar B (current number:17) : 2
How many in Jar C (current number:23) : 1
How many in Jar D (current number:34) : 3
How many in Jar E (current number:19) : 0
```

4) And now your dataframe looks like:

```r
> df
  Jars Cookie
1    A      9
2    B     15
3    C     22
4    D     31
5    E     19
```

Does it correspond to what you are looking for ?

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking to do, thank you so much!!